# Magento 2.4.5 on local Xampp - Elasticsearch issue

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

So I'm trying to install Magento 2.4.5-p1 on my local Windows 10 machine using xampp.

I have installed elasticsearch and it runs fine when testing using the http://localhost:9200/

But when I come to install magento, I'm getting the error:

"In SearchConfig.php line 81:
Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. Unknown 401 error from Elasticsearch null"

I can't seem to find the fix!

Any ideas out there?

Many Thanks in advance

Andy

Comment: Make sure that your Elasticsearch version is compatible with the version of Magento you are using. You can find a list of Elasticsearch versions that are compatible with Magento 2.4.5-p1 in the Magento documentation

Comment: For Magento 2.4.5, Elasticsearch version 7.9.x is recommended.

Comment: Thank you guys - you were correct Harun. I needed version 7